# OneWireException Specified adapter name DS9097U is not known

Tags: android, exception

I am connecting a IButton device to android device,and i try to access the DSPortAdapter OneWireException Specified adapter name DS9097U is not known exception is generated.

```
 try
    {
    DSPortAdapter   access = OneWireAccessProvider.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (access == null)
            throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
        System.out.println("Couldn't get default adapter!");
        return;
    }
```